# Position of a vertex in Box2d

Tags: objective-c, box2d, vertex

How can I get the position of a vertex in Box2d?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: i have a fixture which shape is made by b2PolygonShape, and i need to determinate coordinates of the polygon vertex. The problem is that the shape is rotating

Answer (score 1):

Im just guessing here, but I think you can do something like, getting the fixture list from the body, then getting the shape and from the shape take the vertex (b2Vec2). Then call on the body:

```
b2Vec2 GetWorldPoint (const b2Vec2 &localPoint) const
```

I'm hoping it will take into account the current transformation applied to the body.

Hope it helps!